# composition of multi-tiered visual elements using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wish to build customized widgets using angularjs. My problem is that I want to be able to loosely couple my widgets.

In my case, I wish to build a two level component:

- a graphical spinner
- a progress widget that takes the spinner as an `argument`.

I have built the spinner - http://jsfiddle.net/Byg6W/

I wish to write the progress widget as this:

```
<gh:progress data="progress">
   <gh:spinner .... options ....> </gh:spinner>
</gh:progress>
```

and somehow be able to 'wire' together the two components so that when 'data' updates, it automatically feeds into the gh:spinner, as opposed to what I am loathed to do - putting all the options for gh:spinner into gh:progress

```
<gh:progress data="progress" .... options ....></gh:progress>
```

and then using a template.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a controller on your gh:progress directive that gets called by gh:spinner.  Your gh:spinner can have this controller injected into its link: function by asking for it via the require: property.  Here, you'd use ^ in the require to tell it to look for the controller on parent elements.

See the require: specification on http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.

Check out the Tabs example at the bottom of the angularjs.org home page to see it in action.  Here, the pane directives require the parent tabs' controller so they can register and let the tabs control switching between them.